# Change the default background colour for text fields added to PDFs in Preview?

Tags: pdf, preview, font, color

In Preview you can add text fields to PDFs using the text tool on the toolbar. Every time I add such a text field the background colour is reverted to transparent. All other text properties (i.e., size, font, foreground colour etc) are remembered from the last text field when creating a new text field.

**Is there any way to make Preview also remember the background colour setting when adding text fields to PDFs?**

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to make Preview also remember the background colour setting when adding text fields to PDFs?

There is no **Preferences…** *setting* in **Preview** to remember the last used *color* shown in its **Color Well** for the **Fill Color** when using the **Tools** > **Annotate** > **Text** *menu item*, or its **^⌘T** *keyboard shortcut* , or clicking **Text** on its **Markup Toolbar**.

If there is an unpublished *setting* to change the default behavior, i.e. the **Fill Color** is automatically reset to *none* upon the aforementioned actions, I am unaware of it.

---

## Workaround Solution <sup>1</sup>

As **Preview** does remember the last used *color* shown in its **Color Well** for the **Fill Color** on its **Markup Toolbar**, until using the **Tools** > **Annotate** > **Text** *menu item*, or its **^⌘T** *keyboard shortcut*, or clicking **Text** on its **Markup Toolbar**, this allows for the use of a *Service/Quick Action* in **Automator**, using a **Run AppleScript** *action* with **UI Scripting** *code*, to then be assigned a *keyboard shortcut* that when pressed will automate the process of setting the last used *fill color* to a new *text field*.

- <sup>1</sup> <sub>The *colors* used in this workaround are from the *standard pallet* as shown when clicking on **Fill Color** on the **Markup Toolbar**, and shown in the image below.</sub>

[image]

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested under **macOS High Sierra** thru **macOS Big Sur**, with **Language & Region** set to **English (US)** in **System Preferences**, and worked for me without issue, sans adding **Preview** in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

Using **Automator** I created a *Service/Quick Action* setting **Workflow receives [no input] in [Preview]**, with a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the default *code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below.

Saved the **Automator** *workflow* as **Preview - Add Text with last Fill Color**, then assigned a *keyboard shortcut* of **⇧⌘T** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** for the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    if not (exists front window) or ¬
        not (visible of front window) ¬
            then return
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Preview"
        if (exists menu item ¬
            "Show Markup Toolbar" of ¬
            menu "View" of first menu bar) then ¬
            click menu item "Show Markup Toolbar" of ¬
                menu "View" of first menu bar
        tell front window
            tell (toolbars whose ¬
                description is "edit toolbar")
                set lastFillColor to the ¬
                    value of every color well whose ¬
                    help is "Fill Color"
                click (every button ¬
                    whose description is "Text")
                tell (every color well whose ¬
                    help is "Fill Color")
                    click
                    click (every button of ¬
                        UI element 2 of ¬
                        UI element 1 whose ¬
                        description is ¬
                        lastFillColor)
                    if result is missing value then
                        click (every button of ¬
                            UI element 3 of ¬
                            UI element 1 whose ¬
                            description is ¬
                            lastFillColor)
                    end if
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

[image]

---

## Notes

If you'd prefer to use the default *keyboard shortcut* (**⌃⌘T**) for the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, then you can change the default *keyboard shortcut* used by **Preview** by adding it to: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

Click the **[+]** *button* and set:

- **Application: [Preview]**
- **Menu Title: Text**
- **Keyboard Shortcut: ⇧⌘T**

Then assigned a *keyboard shortcut* of **⌃⌘T** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** for the, e.g. **Preview - Add Text with last Fill Color** *Service/Quick Action*.

---

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown, as is, worked under **macOS High Sierra** thru **macOS Big Sur** without needing to be modified, nonetheless, future releases of **macOS** may require modifications beyond any localizations done for other settings with **Language & Region** when set to other than **English (US)** in **System Preferences**.

---

For this **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, as coded, to work properly, in regards to **Accessibility** settings and **Automation** settings, one should be prompted to allow certain *events* and you may see messages such as:

- The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed assistive access.”
- “Preview“ would to control this computer using accessibility features. Grant access to this application in Security & Privacy > Privacy preferences, located in System Preferences.
- “Preview“ wants access to control “System Events“. Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in “System Events“, and to perform actions within that app.
- Or similar type messages.

This means under:

- **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

  - **Preview** needs to be added and checked.
- **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Automation**

  - **Preview** should show with **System Events** checked.

As applicable to the version of **macOS** this is run under.

---

All testing was done on an **Intel** based **Mac** and I cannot speak to whether or not any of this, as is, will work on an **M1** based **Mac**.

---

**How It Works**

In the first `tell` *block*, **Preview** checks that a *window* exists and is not *minimized*, otherwise the remaining *code* would fail, and stops the *script* if the conditions warrants.

In the second `tell` *block*, **System Events** does the following:

- Checks whether or not the **Markup Toolbar** is showing and if not, shows it.
- Reads the current *value* of the selected *color* of the **Color Well** for the **Fill Color**, assigning it to the `lastFillColor` *variable*.
- Creates the **Text** annotation.
- Sets the *fill color* of the **Text** annotation to the *value* stored in the `lastFillColor` *variable*.

---

Understanding the *code* for clicking the **Color Palette**

Unfortunately **UI Scripting** is necessary to perform the task required to set the *fill color* by clicking on the *color palette* just as if being done manually, however, automating this certainly beats dealing with continued manual repetition.

In the image of the **Color Palette** below, you will see how its broken-down into three `UI elements`.   `UI element2` and `UI element 3` are two distinct sections of the *color palette*.

[image]

As I tend to use the *colors* from the larger selection (`UI element 2`), I've coded it to *click* this section first, and if the target is not there, I click the smaller section (`UI element 3`).

I'm mentioning this so if you typically choose a *color* from the smaller section (`UI element 3`), you'll want to switch the numbers of the two `UI elements`, switching `2` for `3` and `3` for `2` in the *code* shown below.

```applescript
tell (every color well whose ¬
    help is "Fill Color")
    click
    click (every button of ¬
        UI element 2 of ¬
        UI element 1 whose ¬
        description is ¬
        lastFillColor)
    if result is missing value then
        click (every button of ¬
            UI element 3 of ¬
            UI element 1 whose ¬
            description is ¬
            lastFillColor)
    end if
end tell
```

---

<sub>The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans the included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>